# Automatically suspend process

Tags: linux, windows, performance, suspend

I saw that Windows/Linux has the ability to suspend a process.
It is wired for me why background applications are not suspended automatically.

For example, lots of resources are used by Chrome when it is in the background. Easily it can be suspended. So it will stay in RAM and it can unsuspend quickly but it will not use CPU and GPU.

My question contains two parts:

1. Why Windows/Linux (or applications) don't use suspend feature? (sth similar to pause in Android but in the different way)
2. Is there any way to suspend a background task and unsuspend it when it gets focus (when it goes to foreground)?

Comment: 1. Having an OS that allows programs to continue to run in the background is very useful. There are other ways to manage resource use but that kind of management should be configurable and not mandated for all cases. 2. In Linux the `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` signals can be used to suspend and restart a process.

Comment: Question 1 doesn't make sense. Windows *does* suspend UWP applications. That requires infrastructure and cooperation of applications, that wasn't available decades ago, when Windows was developed, so the system relies on Desktop applications to do the right thing.

Comment: @kaylum yes i know there is sigstop and sigcont signal but i mean sth like android system (not exactly the same) which automatically pause a background application and resume when it is in foreground.

Comment: @llnspectable i explained more in the last comment. i mean even the new Microsoft edge doesn't using the suspend feature. it means that this feature is useless. however my second question was about a third party application which is able to unsuspend an application when it is coming back to the foreground

Comment: With respect, you do not appear to understand, how programs run, or why and when they consume resources. A desktop application, that's in the background and doesn't do anything (like, say, Notepad), doesn't execute **any** code at all. It just sits there, waiting for a message to arrive in its call to `GetMessage`. When that happens, the thread scheduler wakes the thread, so that it can dispatch the message. Besides, applications don't *"stay in RAM"*. Virtual memory has been around for literally decades (that's plural). RAM is a performance optimization.

Comment: i understand but i believe that applications are not designed for resource saving in desktop applications. for example i have vscode which is completely in the background but it uses half of my gpu or chrome uses a lots of cpu for its background tabs.@llnspectable

Comment: And what do you propose the OS should do? Suspend those processes, and thereby breaking them?

Comment: what do you think about android design?i think it could be optional. some applications don't need any background process. at least after some minutes. I think os should control. maybe some white list is needed. @llnspectable

Comment: We are going in circles. Windows *already* does that, for UWP applications. It can do this, because UWP's application model allows the system to notify applications when they are about to be put into a suspended state, giving applications the option to respond accordingly. The classic Desktop application model has no such infrastructure. It was designed decades ago. Back then it was a reasonable assumption, that developers could be trusted to do the right thing. As you have noticed, that assumption is no longer reasonable, but it's too late to change the application model.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for your response. My main concern was about memory usage. i have found that we can clear workspace memory easily so it will reduce the unused memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process like Chrome might *not have input focus* on the user interface but still be "running."  (Chrome consists of a set of related processes and threads.)

Yes, Linux *does* have the ability to actually "suspend" a process using the `STOP/CONT` signals, but this would be disruptive to the user interface because Chrome, now being *literally* frozen, could no longer respond to messages sent to it by the user interface.

Processes and threads only consume CPU resources when they actually need to (they are "runnable"), and then only when the operating system gives them a time-slice.  If a thread or process is, say, "waiting for the user interface to send it a message," it's not considered to be "runnable" until a message arrives.

It's also typical that, when a process doesn't have input focus, its *priority* is slightly reduced so that it always gives-way to the process that does.  In some systems, the priority is even more reduced when you minimize the window.  (When several processes are "runnable," the operating system uses "priority" to help it to decide which one to run next.)

Comment: i know there is suspend feature but while it is not used by applications, it means that it is useless. I'm seeing the chrome and vscode are always consume my cpu and gpu but they are really not used. they are completely on the background so while these applications are not well written, i want the operation system to suspend them when they are on the background (sth like pause feature in android os)

Comment: Currently windows is using this feature in windows 11 and it is awful it wont unsuspend a process automatically it just suspend the process